# Python Pandas iterate through list and map

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I'm trying to make a simple script that should get the id of an item and get some stats associated with it and add it to the dataframe.

```
stats = ['info_attack', 'info_defense', 'info_magic', 'info_difficulty', 'stats_hp', 'stats_hpperlevel', 'stats_mp', 'stats_mpperlevel',
         'stats_movespeed', 'stats_armor', 'stats_armorperlevel', 'stats_spellblock', 'stats_spellblockperlevel', 'stats_attackrange',
         'stats_hpregen','stats_hpregenperlevel', 'stats_crit', 'stats_critperlevel','stats_attackdamage','stats_attackdamageperlevel',
         'stats_attackspeedperlevel', 'stats_attackspeed']

ngrams = pd.concat([champItemMonoCombinations,champItemBiCombinations,champItemTriCombinations, champItemFourCombinations, champItemPentaCombinations,champItemSexCombinations ])



for stat in stats:
    print(stat)
    ngrams[stat] = ngrams['ChampionID'].map(champDataFrame.set_index('key')[stat])
```

It returns nan and I don't know why

Edit: I was comparing the integer stored in one dataframe with the string in the other one. It works beautifully now

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.replace` instead of `.map`:

```
for stat in stats:
    print(stat)
    ngrams[stat] = ngrams['ChampionID'].replace(champDataFrame.set_index('key')[stat])
```